# CSS: text wrapping prematurely in div

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to stop the following text from wrapping prematurely. Look at the end of the second line, the word "advising" should not have wrapped at that point, there's clearly enough room for it:

[image]

This is the CSS class applied to the `<p>` tag surrounding the text:

```
.teamp {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: MuseoSans;
}
```

If I remove the `font-size` declaration it looks like this:

[image]

If I remove the `font-family` declaration it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like the wrapping is calculated before the `font-size` and/or `font-family` is calculated.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you recreate in a jsfiddle with the font you used?

Comment: @Brian - it's very difficult because there are a lot of nested divs for containers, columns etc.

Comment: A paragraph with that text, dimensions and those stylings would do, otherwise its hard to test.

Comment: @Brian - the font is Adobe Typekit, I'm not sure how to link to that in JSFiddle. Without that, I don't think it'll be very useful

Comment: This may be way off the mark, but check the pasted text content for any rogue `&nbsp;`s? (just a thought, I've seen it happen)

Comment: You should be using relative font sizes in any case.  Try `font-size: 120%; line-height: 130%;` and See What Happens (tm). Adjust as needed.

Comment: @BobBrown - using relative sizes doesn't make any difference to the problem

Comment: Either there is something pathological about the font or something pathological about the text itself.  Without the font, and with hand-typed text, it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7qqc9u1p/  (I note that it "works right" in your example without font-size; I'm not sure what that means, but I think it clears the text of having problems.)  Edit: Unless there is a non-breaking space or something that behaves that way between "advising" and "companies."

Comment: Thanks for your help. After further experimentation, I don't believe it's the font, either, as I'm able to create the problem with a different font. I really am stumped.

Comment: I can duplicate the problem in the fiddle by putting a Unicode non-breaking space (U+00A0) between "advising" and "companies."  I'd verify that the character set specification is "UTF-8" and manually retype those two words and the space between them.  If that doesn't work, I don't have a clue.